# Pentaho Report for OpenERP

Tags: odoo, pentaho

I made simple Pentaho report for res.parner, I am new comer in Pentaho report, I made simple report using report designer.

Now when I select partners from list suppose I selected 2 partner, than print report, My problem is that It display report for all partners not only selected partners.

Any configuration requires for making report? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in pentaho report designer you need to create parameter with type "object"
named "ids" to received ids that you pass from object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the report is an object based report, not an SQL based report, then the connector will send a value of "ids" through, being the list of selected ids.

In the Pentaho Report Designer, define a parameter:

- **Name:** ids
- **Value Type:** Integer
- **Mandatory:** False
- **Display Type:** Multi Value List
- **Validate Values:** False

These are the most important values.  You can a secondary query with partners that returns ids, for testing, but that is all extra and not required for the main part to work.

Finally, in the Data Source, there are three tabs - **Data Source**, **Search Fields**, **Filters**.  You need to define a filter.  Against the path for res.partner, create a filter that has:

- **Field:** id
- **Comparator:** in
- **Value:** ${ids}